# Accessibility of methods from super-class

Tags: java, inheritance

I have doubts that we can create and reference an object of one class and assign it to its subclass. If so, can we use sub-class methods with that object created?

Here is the example:

```
class Super_Class
{
}

class Sub_Class extends Super_Class
{
}

public class test
{
    public static void main(String a[])
    {
        Super_Class obj;
        obj= new Sub_Class;
    }
}
```

What about the access of methods, I mean which class methods are accessible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The rule of thumb on assigning an object of one type to a reference of another type is the "isA" test. If your super class is `Fruit` and subclass is `Banana`, you can assign: `Fruit obj = new Banana()` **if** `Banana` isA `Fruit`.

I suggest you get a good understanding on inheritance and type system in Java.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is called polymorphism, it is a main part of object object oriented programming

You can do it by using a interface.

For ex.

```
public interface myInterface {
  public void test();
  public int getInt();
}

public class Super_Class {
  public void test() {
 //code here
  }
}

public class Sub_Class extends Super_Class implements myInterface{

public int getInt() {
  return 0;
  }
}
```

It means you can use it like this

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
myInterface subClass = (myInterface) Sub_Class;
}
```

You can now access methods in both classes as long as they are defined in the interface.

Please see the wikipedia page [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_in_object-oriented_programming)